# Page's fetch hook does't update data attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt in mode with `ssr: false`. In nuxts's page `/pages/users/index.vue` I am trying fetch data inside nuxt's hook `fetch` like you can see below.

```
 data () {
    return {
      users: [],
      ...
    }
  },

  async fetch(ctx) {
    const usersData = await ctx.$usersApi.getAll()
    this.users = usersData
    console.log('initialized users', this.users) // here is everything fine, users are filled
  }
```

`usersApi` is just my wrapper for axios. As you can see, I also printed `this.users` if there are some data, but when I use `users` inside template, there are no data at all.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `ctx` but rather `this.$usersApi.getAll()` otherwise you're using the old fetch() hook. Also, if it's not working please provide the code in your template and double check the actual array in your Vue devtools

Comment: @kissu I tried your method but it gives me error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAll'), $usersApi is not accessible in fetch method .. if I used mounted hook, everything works fine, but I would like to use fetch method because I think its better practise in nuxt

Comment: How do you achieve your wrapper? What if you don't have any wrapper?

Comment: @kissu there is only try-catch and mapping to custom interfaces or classes, I tried call directly axios from fetch method but behaved same

Comment: Do you have a [repro]? Try into an `asyncData`for testing purposes. What is your template looking like?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, using it in SSR/static mode. I see that you don't so I think we can conclude that doesn't cause the issue. (Nuxt version 2.15.7)